# Flash or JQuery or Other Graph Visualization

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have two basic bar charts and I am currently using XML/SWF Charts which is great but the problem I have is I need to be able to send these graphs via email to the user. As well as display them on the site.

I know sending Flash is a bad idea, I would love to find a way to convert my current graphs to an image, but am pretty certain there is no quick fix without building a work around myself.

Therefore what are the best open source or closed solutions for this problem.

I need to be able to display two graphs dynamically and then email them to users.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the "Google Image Chart Api" (not to be confused with the Google Chart API).

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/

It allows you to generate numerious different types of charts just from the URL.

For example:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World

That URL could also be put into an HTML e-mail.

Alternatively, looking at this stackoverflow quesiton [FLASH save frame, to image (tiff, bmp, jpg, gif, png)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273221/flash-save-frame-to-image-tiff-bmp-jpg-gif-png)

If you can modify the flash movie. It appears that you can save frames in AS3 via BitmapData. So you may be able to send the data back to the server for processing (emailing). But I can't vouch for this as I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

jqPlot seems pretty good. Piwik uses it. http://www.jqplot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/). It is a javascript library for rendering graphs using svg(or vml for IE8 and below). I've personally use it and it is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work for you since you're not running .net, but for anyone else who's looking for resources for generating charts there's the [MS Chart controls](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422).